# How to mix wordpress taxonomies with a SEO-friendly URL

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

We have a website that provides applications, games, tutorials,... for different mobiles ( android, windows-phone, ios )
Let's say we have two taxonomies for posts 1.`category`2.`operation_system`.

We need to mix these two taxonomies , for example we want to show android applications , One option is two make a URL like this :

`http://example.com/category/apps/?operation_system=android`

And show the content with a `pre_get_posts` action , Which is not SEO-friendly at all.

the better option is to make URLs like this :

`http://example.com/category/apps/android/` or `http://example.com/android/apps/`

For every `taxonomy mix` we create, I want to be able to control `page title`, `description`, `og:image` and other S.E.O-related tags( on admin panel ).

Is there any written plugin for such thing? or what's your solution for such thing, I would appreciate it if someone give me a clue on how to add this feature to my WordPress site.

Comment: The [template system](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) is pretty powerful with respect to custom taxonomy archives.  I'd probably check into useing it to try and accomplish this.

Comment: Also - for the URL's, I'd use the [rewrite_endpoint API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) to create a custom endpoint.  The URL would look more like `http://example.com/category/apps/system/android`, I believe.  But between this and the template system, I think you can make this work.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand it , would explain more please

Comment: No, it's really too large of a question to give a good answer.  Those are just the two tools I would combine: using specific templates for your "category", which *inside of* that template leveraged the *rewrite endpoint* API to pick up the "operating system"

Comment: Did you solved your problem? I'm looking exactly for something like this: ```http://example.com/category/apps/?operation_system=android ```